# Prove that graph $G$ is bipartite iff every $H\subseteq G$ has linearly independent group of vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that graph $G$ is bipartite iff every $H\subseteq G$ has linearly independent group of vertices of size $\leq |V'|/2$. (where $G=(V,E)$ ,$ H=(V',E')$)
I managed to prove the first part myself ($G$ is bipartite $\rightarrow$ $H\subseteq G$ has linearly independent group of vertices).
I got stuck on the second part.
I took $H=G$ and since $H\subseteq G$ it has a group of linearly independent vertices, so I can take them to be group number $1$ of vertices in the bipartite graph. But that doesn't mean the the rest of them is linearly independent.

Comment: Should the $\leq$ be a $\geq$ in your condition?

Comment: By the way, *linearly independent* is a term from linear algebra. In graph theory, one just says an *independent* set of vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming your condition should be that the independent set is of size *at least* half the number of vertices in $H$.)

Recall that a graph is bipartite if and only if it has no cycles of odd length. So if a graph satisfies your condition but is not bipartite, take $H$ to be an odd length cycle. Do you see the contradiction?