# $A \implies B \lor C$, where $B$ is not guaranteed to be true. Can one say $C$ is always true?

Tags: logic

$A \implies B \lor C$, where $B$ is not guaranteed to be true. Can one say $C$ is always true?

Can I argue that $C$ needs to hold even if $B$ does not hold to prove $C$?

Edit: I will include the precise problem.

Let it be true that for every subgraph $H \subseteq G$ there exists a set $X\subseteq V(H)$ of pairwise non-adjancent vertices such that $|X|\geq \frac{|V(H)|}{2}$.

Consider all vertices $v_i \in V(G)$ and two sets $M_1, M_2$. Move all vertices from $V(G)$ to $M_1$ and let $M_2$ be empty. Now run through all $v_i \in M_1$ . For a fixed $v_i$, run through all $v_j, j \neq i$. If $v_i$ and $v_j$ are adjancent, move $v_j$ to $M_2$. After running through all $i$, all vertices in $M_1$ are pairwise non-adjancent.

Now I want to show that no pair of vertices in $M_2$ is adjancent. For that I use the assumption I made about existence of $X$. Run through all $v_k \in M_2$. For a fixed $v_k$ consider a $v_{m} \in M_1$ such that $v_k$ and $v_m$ are adjancent ($v_m$ exists since $v_k$ has been moved to $M_2$ due to this connection). Now run through all $v_n \in M_2$ and consider the subgraph $H$ with $V(H)=\{ v_k, v_m, v_n \}$. Now using the assumption, $|X|=2$, since $v_k, v_m$ are adjacent. Now it follows that $X=\{v_k, v_n\}$, meaning that all pairs in $M_2$ are non-adjancent or $X= \{v_m, v_n\}$, which does not always apply, since there can be a graph $G$ with an edge connecting $v_m, v_n$. Does this prove that $X=\{v_k, v_n\}$?

Comment: What if $A$ is false?

Comment: $A$ is given to be always true.

Comment: If your implication is always true, where $A$ is given to be true and $B$ is allowed to be either True or False, then $C$ must always be true to guarantee that your implication is true (it is obviously false when $B$ is false and $C$ is false).

Comment: What do you mean by saying "$B$ is not guaranteed to be true"? Do you just mean that it's truth value is unknown?  In any case, what if $C=\neg B$?  Then $B\vee \neg B$ is always true

Comment: @Hayden Well what does it mean to prove $C$? Prove what about it? This question is currently not very well posed.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow Agreed, the OP needs to clarify the question quite a bit

Comment: My question is very specific. I have a set of statements. $A$ is always true, $B$ is only true for certain types of graphs and I need to prove that $C$ is always true.

Comment: I believe that under a set of statements, $B$ can either be "always" true or "always" false. It can't be both unless there is some contradiction.

Comment: $A$ is true for all graphs, $B$ is true only for certain graphs, I am trying to prove that $C$ is true for all graphs.

Comment: @B.Schnebbler It sounds like you have a predicates, not propositions, like you want to show $(\forall g_1. A(g_1)) \land \lnot(\forall g_2.B(g_2)) \land (\forall g_3. A(g_3)\to B(g_3)\lor C(g_3))\implies \forall g_4.C(g_4)$ or something. This particular implication doesn't hold though, you essentially get $\forall g.B(g)\lor C(g)$ and nothing stops $C(g)$ from being false whenever $B(g)$ happens to be true. For example, if $g$ were a number, $B$ could be the "is even" predicate and $C$ the "is odd" predicate and jointly they would be true for all numbers even though neither is individually.

Comment: I have updated the problem: It is terriby specific, excuse me. That is why I wanted to ask more generally, but it seems to cause confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly neither is true. As @DerekElkins points out, if you're using terminology such as "always," you probably want first order quantification. In particular, you're probably looking for something like the following statement:

$$(\forall x. A(x) \implies B(x) \lor C(x)) \land (\exists y. \lnot B(y)) \implies (\forall z. A(z) \implies C(z))$$

Unfortunately this is not true and @DerekElkins's example is again a good one: all integers are either even or odd. Just because not all integers are even doesn't mean all integers are odd.

The specific proposition you're trying to prove, namely that $M_2$ as you've constructed must have pairwise disconnected vertices is also false. In particular, consider the "straight line" four-vertex graph, i.e. where $V = \{A, B, C, D\}$ with edges $AB, BC, CD$.

If I follow your construction, then one possible result is to start at $A$, which moves $B$ to $M_2$. Then I examine $D$, moving $C$ to $M_2$. Thus $M_2$ consists of $\{B, C\}$.

Comment: Sir, you have disproven me: Thank you.

Comment: I have developed a correct way of the proof here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063584/question-regarding-bipartite-graphs-and-their-subgraphs, if you would like to review it. Thank you again for the correction!